# How to Implement test doubles (stand in mocks) in PHPunit, what triviality am I missing?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am probably missing something really trivial here, but I cannot get phpunit to use stand-in Mocked classes.

Below is an example where `Foo` is the class that I am testing and `Bar` the class that I want to Mock out.

I would expect below example to pass, since I have mocked `Bar`, stubbed out `Bar::heavy_lifting` to return "not bar" and then call that trough `Foo::do_stuff()`. 
Yet it fails, the example still returns "bar", seems to completely ignore my stubbing.

```
class Foo {
  public function do_stuff() {
    $b = new Bar();
    return $b->heavy_lifting();
  }
}

class Bar {
  public function heavy_lifting() {
    return "bar";
  }
}

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testBar() {
    $fake     = "not bar";
    $stand_in = $this->getMock("Bar");
    $stand_in->expects($this->any())
             ->method("heavy_lifting")
             ->will($this->returnValue($fake));

    $foo = new Foo();
    $this->assertEquals($foo->do_stuff(), $fake);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work as expected. Stub is not about replacing Bar class, but to create objects that can be passed to where Bar is expected. You should refactor your Foo class like:

```
class Foo {

    /* inject your dependency to Foo, it can be injected in many ways,
       using constructor, setter, or DI Container */

    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public  function do_stuff() {
        $this->bar->heavy_lifting();
    }

}
```

Than you can pass mocked Bar to class Foo.

Comment: Any code that uses `new` directly makes testing difficult. Move it to a factory or DI container.

Comment: In my implementation, Foo is the only one bothered with Bar and Heavy lifting; in your example, the caller suddenly needs to be bothered with Bar. Doesn't that break the principle of "tell don't ask", where outside needs to know as little as possible about the innards of Bar?

Comment: Well, there are lots of principles and some of them are somehow contradictiong. In DI thinking, it is always "let the caller supply all the dependencies, no hidden dependencies should exists". In other words, if class has any dependencies, all have to be clearly visible through API, in our example through constructor.

Comment: @berkes "the caller suddenly needs to be bothered with Bar". Yes, and I agree it sucks. So offer a default for that constructor parameter, that will create a Bar object just as your current code does. Then your test code becomes the only one to specify that parameter. (BTW, as Jasir's code comment says, using a construtor parameter is just one approach; the key is that you have a `$this->bar` that your unit test code can set.)